# karate docker compose implementation on linux os is possible or not?

Tags: karate

Is there a way to write docker compose for karate image in Linux OS ? if yes then plz share feedback

Used following link :
karate docker - https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/Docker
karate document - https://karatelabs.github.io/karate/karate-core/

[karate]

We are trying to implement karate ui automation using docker compose for linux OS.

Comment: "[Some end goal]: Possible or not?" is not the kind of thing we do here, if you don't describe why you think it might not be possible. Write a question about a _specific_ thing that stopped you from being able to implement this yourself, with enough detail that someone else can create that problem themselves.

Comment: you may want to read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

I think this will answer your question: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-examples/blob/main/docker/README.md

This is a simple `Dockerfile` that should get you up and running using Karate:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk:11-jre-hotspot

RUN  apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y wget \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN wget -O karate.jar https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/releases/download/v1.4.0/karate-1.4.0.jar
```

Comment: Can we pass maven related command through this image ?

Comment: @SushilPawar no. for that refer this: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/Get-Started:-Other-Runtime-Options#docker